# "May" and "might", can you explain me?

Tags: modal-verbs, word-difference, auxiliary-verbs

"May" and "might", I have been confusing about these words but I wasn't able to find satisfactory answers. Can you explain it to me. Similar can and could is also confusing.

Answer (score 1):

"Might" is the past tense of "may," but they are often used interchangeably. Similar with "can" and "could."

Mind you, using "could" when you are making requests is more polite than using "can." For instance, "Could you do that for me?" is more polite than "Can you do that for me?"

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts, the words **may** and **might** can work as interchangeable synonyms:

> *We **may** go for a walk on Sunday afternoon, if the weather is nice*.
>   *We **might** go for a walk on Sunday afternoon, if the weather is nice*.

In this case, the words *may* and *might* indicate that something is a possibility, but not a certainty.

---

Other times, **may** and **can** function as interchangable synonyms, meaning that someone has permission to do something:

> *You **can** have a cookie if you want one*.
>   *You **may** have a cookie if you want one*.

---

And there are other times where **can** and **could** can work in similar ways, to indicate an ability to do something:

> *We **can** get warmer if we build a fire*.
>   *We **could** be warmer if we built a fire*.

In this context, these words function as [modal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb), meaning they reference certain possibilities – in other words, things that might, can, or could happen.

---

As you probably have discovered in your research, each of the words you ask about is a very flexible word with many different possible usages. I don't feel I can give a complete answer here, but I can at least try to explain a few of the more basic similarities and differences.